# In a ggplot object, how to increase the space in the lines of caption

Tags: r, ggplot2

I find there is a temporal way to change the text size of the caption. However, I am just searching for a safer solution.
Typically, I go through all arguments in the function `theme` with `caption*`, but I cannot find an argument to deal with it.

---

Here is a reproducible minimal example for the suggestion from @Tung.

The only difference between the 1st figure and the 2nd one is the space width of the two lines in the caption.
For my preference, I think one-line width is too wider, how to get it like 50% one-line width.

```
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(mpg, disp) +
    geom_point() -> p
p + 
    labs(caption = 'line1\nline2')
```

[image]

```
p + 
    labs(caption = 'line1\n\nline2')
```

[image]

---

I don't use the function `reprex` to get the output because of this error.

```
> reprex(si = T)
Rendering reprex...
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: Connection timed out after 10001 milliseconds
```

By the way, I cannot use the function `reprex` with the output picture because of the connection restrictions in China.
This issue I talks with @yihui and @jennybc on one GitHub Issue for a long time, it is hard to fix and only to wait for an available one in China.
But all code I provide I think is enough to reproduce the figures.

---

Thanks for the @Gregor 's solution, here is an example to display this idea.

```r
mtcars %>% 
    ggplot() +
    aes(mpg, disp) +
    geom_point() +
    labs(caption = 'line1\nline2') -> p0
# p0
p0 + theme(plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 1.5)) -> p1
p0 + theme(plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 2.0)) -> p2
p0 + theme(plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 3.0)) -> p3
p0 + p1 + p2 + p3 + plot_layout(nrow = 2,byrow = T)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `theme(plot.caption = geom_text(...))`?

Comment: I think @Z.Lin meant `theme(plot.caption = element_text(size = ..., vjust = ...))`. Alternatively, you can just add `\n` before your caption to add an extra line to it.

Comment: @Tung Thanks for pointing out! was typing in a hurry...

Comment: Hi, @Tung, I think it is a manual way. But if I want to just 0.5 widths ... Because sometimes 1 space is too large, 0.5 is better.

Comment: @Jiaxiang: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Comment: @Tung, I add it in the content, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the `lineheight` for the caption text.

```
p + labs(caption = 'line1\nline2') +
  theme(plot.caption = element_text(lineheight = 1.5))
```

I think this is equivalent to "line spacing", that is `1` is singlespaced, `2` is doublespaced, etc.

If found the solution by looking at the `?theme` help page and searching for "caption". This revealed the `plot.caption` theme setting, and sad it was `element_text`. I followed the link to `?element_text` and saw the `lineheight` argument.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution and respect to your problem-solving process. It is practical and clear.